# Naming: time you have to wait before something is valid

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

We are tracking offline conversions in google adwords and have to wait 4-6 hours after the click before a conversion can be attached to it.

I have a constant that references this time and it is currently called `CLICK_GESTATION_HOURS`, which is kind of a play on the standard life-cycle terms such as 'expiry'.

It got me wondering, is there a standard computing term for the time you have to wait before something is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard computing term for "the time you have to wait before something is valid", but a common computing term used for waiting is (obviously!) "wait" or "delay".

In my opinion "CLICK_GESTATION_HOURS" is not a good choice of variable name as it is very ambiguous i.e. the term gestation implies that click is going to give birth to something (another click?!).

How about using an [intention revealing](http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83) name such as "ClickConversionAttachmentDelay"?

Comment: Thanks Ben, although I would point out that expiry suggests a death; albeit to a lesser degree than gestation implies a birth (time for the click to be birthed - not give birth to anything). I do prefer your name however.

Comment: Glad I could help @Arth :) Where did I mention expiry? I too find that getting a good name for a variable/method can sometimes be harder than implementing the functionality!

Comment: Oh I mentioned that 'gestation' was a play on the existing standard term 'expiry' in my question was all. I agree with your last statement and would add that it's importance is often overlooked.